# Scan MD5 in Process Running vb.net

Tags: vb.net, md5

I Have Antivirus Form 
i want scan the application running and found the md5 hash and not the process (only MD5) and i want `do some action` if the md5 same with my TextBox, anyone can help me how to do that?

Thank you before 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I've posted a link to help with this. Did you try the code? Get errors?

Comment: Yes i'm try and is work, but i'm want hash md5 in process running, not by the folder, can you help me sir?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the filename by making an array of the running processes
Then you can build a function that does an MD5 of all processes found.
Maybe if you split your idea into many small chunks you will get forward easier.

I'd try to create an array of the processes and their paths (see my snippet).
Then you can write that to another Array where you add the checksum that you calculated in the line and use a split-character like ";"
So one line of your array could be "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;afd4383f8d8fd"

Then you can loop through the processes, do an MD5 of your process and then look it up in the array you wrote, it will lookup the Filepath as ID and then it will compare the MD5 in the array with the one you calculated again. 
When you put that on a timer with a tick of like 5 seconds you could kind of "seal " your application-sums and let a warning appear if there is a mismatch or something else.

```
 Dim Processfinder() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()

    For Each pr In Processfinder
        Dim Prstring As String = pr.StartInfo.FileName.ToString
    Next
```

Since i built something similar a while ago: 
You have to be aware that you cannot see all processes if your program is 32 bit and your OS is 64 bit.